# Printing string fields in Ruby

Tags: ruby, awk

I have this string in the variable `var`:

> cheese dogs cats alligators

I know I could get the second field in this string " dogs" using awk if I was on a linux command line.

```
> cat var | awk '{print $2}'
dogs
```

But how would I do this in Ruby?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We'd prefer to see your attempt to solve this, rather than toss out code. What have you tried? Why didn't it work to your satisfaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby has a [`String#split` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) that splits on whitespace by default, returning an array whose second element can then be accessed:

```
irb(main):001:0> 'cheese dogs cats alligators'.split
=> ["cheese", "dogs", "cats", "alligators"]
irb(main):002:0> 'cheese dogs cats alligators'.split[1]
=> "dogs"
```

Answer (score 0):

> echo cheese dogs cats alligators  | ruby -ne 'puts $_.split[1] '